# Acumatica How to get the Cash Account Begin or Ending Balance?

Tags: api, acumatica

When I select a Cash Account in the "Founds Transfers" (CA301000), **GL Balance** and **Avaliable Balance** Entries are updated.

Where these amounts come from? I mean, I need to query these field via GI but I cannot figure out the Table's name.

Any Clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL Balance and Available Balance fields are part of the CATransfer DAC.
You won't find them in the CATransfer database table because they are calculated at runtime in CATransfer DAC as unbound fields using the FieldSelecting events of GLBalanceAttribute and CashBalanceAttribute.

You can find out the DAC and Data Field of a UI element by holding Ctl+Alt and clicking on that field.

For reference, here are the GLBalance attributes inCATransfer Dac:

```
    #region InGLBalance
    public abstract class inGLBalance : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _InGLBalance;

    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXCury(typeof(CATransfer.inCuryID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "GL Balance", Enabled = false)]
    [GLBalance(typeof(CATransfer.inAccountID), null, typeof(CATransfer.inDate))]
    public virtual Decimal? InGLBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InGLBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            this._InGLBalance = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region OutGLBalance
    public abstract class outGLBalance : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _OutGLBalance;

    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXCury(typeof(CATransfer.outCuryID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "GL Balance", Enabled = false)]
    [GLBalance(typeof(CATransfer.outAccountID), null, typeof(CATransfer.outDate))]
    public virtual Decimal? OutGLBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OutGLBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            this._OutGLBalance = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is the GLBalanceAttribute class FieldSelecting event where the value is calculated:

```
    public virtual void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        GLSetup gLSetup = PXSelect<GLSetup>.Select(sender.Graph);
        decimal? result = 0m;
        object CashAccountID = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _CashAccount);

        object FinPeriodID = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_FinPeriodID))
        {
            object FinDate = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FinDate);
            FinPeriod finPeriod = PXSelect<FinPeriod, Where<FinPeriod.startDate, LessEqual<Required<FinPeriod.startDate>>,
                                                        And<FinPeriod.endDate, Greater<Required<FinPeriod.endDate>>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, FinDate, FinDate);
            if (finPeriod != null)
            {
                FinPeriodID = finPeriod.FinPeriodID;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FinPeriodID = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FinPeriodID);
        }

        if (CashAccountID != null && FinPeriodID != null)
        {
            // clear glhistory cache for ReleasePayments longrun
            sender.Graph.Caches<GLHistory>().ClearQueryCache();
            sender.Graph.Caches<GLHistory>().Clear();

            GLHistory gLHistory = PXSelectJoin<GLHistory,
                                                InnerJoin<GLHistoryByPeriod,
                                                        On<GLHistoryByPeriod.accountID, Equal<GLHistory.accountID>,
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.branchID, Equal<GLHistory.branchID>,
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.ledgerID, Equal<GLHistory.ledgerID>,
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.subID, Equal<GLHistory.subID>,
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.lastActivityPeriod, Equal<GLHistory.finPeriodID>>>>>>,
                                                InnerJoin<Branch,
                                                        On<Branch.branchID, Equal<GLHistory.branchID>,
                                                        And<Branch.ledgerID, Equal<GLHistory.ledgerID>>>,
                                                InnerJoin<CashAccount,
                                                        On<GLHistoryByPeriod.branchID, Equal<CashAccount.branchID>, 
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.accountID, Equal<CashAccount.accountID>,
                                                        And<GLHistoryByPeriod.subID, Equal<CashAccount.subID>>>>,
                                                InnerJoin<Account,
                                                        On<GLHistoryByPeriod.accountID, Equal<Account.accountID>, 
                                                        And<Match<Account, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
                                                InnerJoin<Sub,
                                                        On<GLHistoryByPeriod.subID, Equal<Sub.subID>, And<Match<Sub, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>>>>,
                                                Where<CashAccount.cashAccountID, Equal<Required<CashAccount.cashAccountID>>,
                                                   And<GLHistoryByPeriod.finPeriodID, Equal<Required<GLHistoryByPeriod.finPeriodID>>>
                                                 >>.Select(sender.Graph, CashAccountID, FinPeriodID);

            if (gLHistory != null)
            {
                result = gLHistory.CuryFinYtdBalance;
            }
        }
        e.ReturnValue = result;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here are the CashBalance attributes of CATransfer Dac:

```
    #region CashBalanceIn
    public abstract class cashBalanceIn : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _CashBalanceIn;
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXCury(typeof(CATransfer.inCuryID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Available Balance", Enabled = false)]
    [CashBalance(typeof(CATransfer.inAccountID))]
    public virtual Decimal? CashBalanceIn
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CashBalanceIn;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CashBalanceIn = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region CashBalanceOut
    public abstract class cashBalanceOut : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _CashBalanceOut;
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXCury(typeof(CATransfer.outCuryID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Available Balance", Enabled = false)]
    [CashBalance(typeof(CATransfer.outAccountID))]
    public virtual Decimal? CashBalanceOut
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CashBalanceOut;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CashBalanceOut = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And the CashBalanceAttribute class FieldSelecting event where the value is calculated:

```
    public virtual void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        CASetup caSetup = PXSelect<CASetup>.Select(sender.Graph);
        decimal? result = 0m;
        object CashAccountID = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _CashAccount);

        CADailySummary caBalance = PXSelectGroupBy<CADailySummary,
                                                     Where<CADailySummary.cashAccountID, Equal<Required<CADailySummary.cashAccountID>>>,
                                                                Aggregate<Sum<CADailySummary.amtReleasedClearedCr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtReleasedClearedDr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtReleasedUnclearedCr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtReleasedUnclearedDr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtUnreleasedClearedCr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtUnreleasedClearedDr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtUnreleasedUnclearedCr,
                                                                 Sum<CADailySummary.amtUnreleasedUnclearedDr>>>>>>>>>>.
                                                                 Select(sender.Graph, CashAccountID);
        if ((caBalance != null) && (caBalance.CashAccountID != null))
        {
            result = caBalance.AmtReleasedClearedDr - caBalance.AmtReleasedClearedCr;

            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalDebitClearedUnreleased)
                result += caBalance.AmtUnreleasedClearedDr;
            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalCreditClearedUnreleased)
                result -= caBalance.AmtUnreleasedClearedCr;
            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalDebitUnclearedReleased)
                result += caBalance.AmtReleasedUnclearedDr;
            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalCreditUnclearedReleased)
                result -= caBalance.AmtReleasedUnclearedCr;
            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalDebitUnclearedUnreleased)
                result += caBalance.AmtUnreleasedUnclearedDr;
            if ((bool)caSetup.CalcBalCreditUnclearedUnreleased)
                result -= caBalance.AmtUnreleasedUnclearedCr;
        }
        e.ReturnValue = result;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```